# ORA-04098 trigger error when trying to restrict character length

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger for my database table so that users can only enter a postcode that is 6-8 characters long. However, this doesn't seem to work even though the trigger doesn't show any errors.

Here is the code:

```
create or replace trigger loc_postcode
before insert or update of postcode
on location
for each row
begin
    if ( LENGTH(:new.postcode) > 8) or ( LENGTH(:new.postcode) < 6)
         then    raise_application_error(0001,
             'The postcode must be between 6 and 8 characters long');
         end if;
end;​
```

and the error:

> ORA-04098: trigger 'C3392387.LOC_ID' is invalid and failed re-validation

Comment: Your trigger has name `loc_postcode` but your error message mentions a trigger named `LOC_ID` - is there an error with that trigger as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned the trouble with the previous version of your trigger was that you were comparing a string to a number when you needed to compare the length of the string to a value. I won't go into any further details on this.

The reason for your current error is that you're not using a valid error code for a user-defined error. Per [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#LNPLS99960) the `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` procedure takes error codes in the range `-20000` to `-20999`. Change the error code to `-20001` and [the trigger will work](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ca29/1).

I'm a little surprised that you were getting the error that you are. I would have expected you to get `"ORA-21000: error number argument to raise_application_error of 1 is out of range"` as can be demonstrated [in this SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1af52/1). It's possibly because you have a slightly dodgy character after your final semi-colon. It's displaying a a space in Hex when I look at it in a text editor, but judging how it appears when I copy it into SQL Fiddle it might not be. It's also possible it's an artefact of Stack Exchange's rendering engine.

Incidentally, `0001` is *not* a valid Oracle error code; [`00001`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/e0.htm) is a unique constraint violation and would be declared as `-00001` (note the minus sign).

However, this is not how I would go about doing this. Triggers incur additional overhead when used and obfuscate constraints that could be declared in the database. There's also always the danger of having cascading triggers, which can make your data-model *extremely* complex.

The simpler method of doing this would be to declare your `POSTCODE` column to be at most 8 characters/bytes (up to you) and to add a [check constraint](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16508/datainte.htm#CHDGBFBJ) on the column to ensure that the length of the postcode is 6 characters (or bytes) or greater. This embeds the logic you need in the structure of the table (and thus in Oracle's metadata), making it a lot easier to see what's going on.

If you were to declare your table DDL as something like the below (obviously massively simplified):

```
create table location ( 
     id number
   , postcode varchar2(8)
   , constraint pk_location primary key (id)
   , constraint ck_location_postcode check (length(postcode) between 6 and 8)
     )
```

Then you can achieve the same result ([working SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ff73c/1)). Note that the maximum length of the column `POSTCODE` is 8, which takes care of the upper bound and there's a further check constraint limiting it. I've defined the check constraint to take care of both the upper and lower bounds so that you can tell in the future that you intended 8 to be the upper bound. A change to the size of the column will not, therefore, break your constraint. It's a safety feature, nothing more and it could be declared as follows without changing the functionality:

```
   , constraint ck_location_postcode check (length(postcode) >= 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want the length not the value:

```
create or replace trigger loc_id 
before insert or update of postcode
on location
for each row
begin
         if (length(:new.postcode) > 8) or (length(:new.postcode) < 6)
         then    raise_application_error(
             'The postcode must be between 6 and 8 characters long');
         end if;
end;
```

Your code doesn't generate an error because Oracle allows you to attempt to compare strings and numbers.  The failure is when the string is not a numeric format.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I changed it like you said and it got rid of one of the errors but the other is still there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like POSTCODE is a string.  Since you are trying to check its length, you need to use the LENGTH function.

```
if ( LENGTH(:new.postcode) > 8) or ( LENGTH(:new.postcode) < 6)
```

or personally I would prefer:

```
if NOT LENGTH(:new.postcode) BETWEEN 6 AND 8 THEN
```

In your version, you are trying to compare the actual value of POSTCODE to the number 6 and 8, which results in an error when the string value can't be converted to a number.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I changed it like you said and it got rid of one of the errors but the other is still there.